# How to redirect single post to parent category

Tags: wp-redirect

The code below redirects single posts to the homepage if a post doesn't contain a certain post_meta.

What id like to happen is instead of redirecting to the homepage`wp_redirect( home_url( '' ), 301 );`

It should redirect to the parent category/custom-taxonomy which the post is residing in.

```
    function custom_disable_single_cpt_views() {
    $queried_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    $cpts_without_single_views = array( 'business' );
    $featured_listing = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "main_listing", TRUE);
    if (    is_single()
        &&  in_array( $queried_post_type, $cpts_without_single_views )
        &&  ("" === $featured_listing)
    ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_disable_single_cpt_views' );
```

So for example my taxonomy is `"location"`,   if a post is in the category called

> "suffolk"

then id like the post to be redirected to the category and not the homepage.

Comment: There is no concept of primary category in WP natively. Could you please narrow down your logic a bit? Maybe with several more specific examples?

Comment: My apologies,  I must have been using a plugin previously which added a "primary", I have just checked on the this install and indeed there is no primary option.   In which case parent category would be a good start,  Is it then possible to redirect by ID if there is more than one category ? Im open to best practice ideas.

Comment: You may want to use 'get_term_link()' to get archive url for the taxonomy term archive you want to display. You have to pass the taxonomy term slug when calling the function, but that shouldn't be a problem since you can retrieve it/them with 'get_terms()'. It may return an array if the post has multiple taxonomy terms.